# Have anyone used Feitian SDK (For POS) in Android?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, point-of-sale

Do anyone know that how to use Feitian SDK to take print from the POS machine in Android or Flutter project?

I have the [docs](https://www.ftsafe.com/payment/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/V8-Feitian-SDK-Introduction.pdf)